# Looping through an animation backwards AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Trying to get an animation to play backwards while a button is held down, which works fine, however when it gets to the first frame it just stops and won't loop back around to the last frame of the animation- how might one accomplish this? It seems like I need to break the event for a frame somehow and then start listening again...

```
backward_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, setDownTrue);
backward_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, setDownFalse);

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkDown);

var isDown:Boolean = false;

function setDownTrue(e:MouseEvent){
    isDown = true;
}

function setDownFalse(e:MouseEvent){
    isDown = false;
}

function checkDown(e:Event){
    if(isDown == true){
        prevFrame();
        if(currentFrame == 1){
            gotoAndStop(120);  //120 is the last frame of the animation
            isDown = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'll post my animation class i did that plays backwards depanding on the speed you set it (-1 to play backward), if you want.

Your code should work, the problem is most likely like you said, doesnt has the time to play its frame to 120 before it gets ask to prevFrame again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ENTER_FRAME` event is not your problem, it continues to trigger. However, `isDown` turns into false on the last frame. You should change `isDown = false;` to `isDown = true;` after the `gotoAndStop` line in order to loop continuously.

Comment: hmmm I will try this in the morning... isDown is already true though at this point, I basically set it to false there so it would trigger as true again right away and continue, unfortunately it needs a new mouse down event to do that... like i said i will try this out

Comment: Can't really explain why, but the isDown variable begins to return false immediately after the gotoAndStop. Just try it, ad a trace(isDown); at the top of the handler for ENTER_FRAME, ouside the if clause.

Answer (score 1):

I actually just helped a co-worker with this:

```
myMovieClip //your instance on the stage
```

lets say you want your movieclip to play backwards on click:

```
myMovieClip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, playBackwards);
}

function playBackwards(e:Event):void
{
    var frame:int = myMovieClip.currentFrame -1; //get frame before current;
    myMovieClip.gotoAndStop(frame); // go to that frame
    if(frame == 1) removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, playBackwards); //if the frame is the first frame then remove the enterframe event
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Save yourself some trouble and use `totalFrames`:

```
if(currentFrame == 1)
    gotoAndStop(totalFrames);

else prevFrame();
```

Comment: PrevFrame() function inside the MovieClip class, the exactly contrary of nextFrame()

:)

Comment: Touche - this is what happens when you aggressively avoid this inbuilt display classes beyond Bitmap ;P

Comment: totalFrames- yes, I was looking for something like this, have added to my code